# Encoding problem from database to javamail

Tags: java, oracle, encoding, jakarta-mail

I have a small application which reads from a Oracle 9i database and sends the data via e-mail, using JavaMail. The database has `NLS_CHARACTERSET = "WE8MSWIN1252"`, that's it, CP1252.

If I run the app without any parameter, it works fine and the e-mails are sent correctly. However, I've a requeriment that enforces me to run the app with the `-Dfile-encoding=utf8` parameter, which results in the text being sent with corrupted characters.

I've tried to change the encoding of the data read from the database, with:

```
String textToSend = new String(textRead.getBytes("CP1252"), "UTF-8");
```

But it doesn't help. I've tried all the possible combinations with `CP1252, windows-1252, ISO-8859-1` and `UTF-8`, but still had no luck.

Any ideas?

---

**Update** to clarify my problem: when I do the following:

```
Statement stat = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stat.executeQuery("SELECT blah FROM blahblah ...");
ResultSet rs = stat.getResultSet();
String textRead = rs.getString("whatever");
```

I get `textRead` corrupted, because the database is CP1252 and the application is running in UTF-8. Another approach that I've tried but also failed:

```
InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream("whatever");
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
String textRead = writer.toString();
```

Comment: Can you post the snippets where you get the text *into* the `textRead` variable, and where you compose the `MimeMessage`?

Comment: I have a similar problem - any pointers appreciated - I have added a bounty to the question!

Comment: I'm sorry - I have been transferred to another project within my company, so I have no access to the database for further testing. Grouchal, given that you've offered a bounty, please feel free to edit the question with more information specific to your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your driver should do the conversion automatically and since cp-1252 is a subset of UTF-8 you shouldn't lose information.

Can you try the following: get the String with `ResultSet.getString`, write the string to a file. Open the file with an editor with which you can specify UTF-8 character set (jEdit for example).

The file should contain UTF-8 data.

Comment: I'm sorry Vincent - I have been transferred to another project within my company, so I have no access to the database for further testing. I hope your advice helps Grouchal - the user who has offered the bounty.

Comment: It turns out that although our problem was similar the real problem was caused by other software so this hasn't helped with the problem. However it is a good answer to the original question.

Comment: I have retaken this issue and finally managed to solve it. You were right, the string was already UTF-8. What I was doing wrong was the javamail part: I was trying `myMimeMessage.setText(text);` instead of `myMimeMessage.setText(text, "utf-8");`.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to get lost in charset space -- i understand this... :-)

This line

```
String textToSend = new String(textRead.getBytes("CP1252"), "UTF-8");
```

does not make much sense. You have already text, convert it to a "cp1252" encoded byte []. Then you tell the VM to treat the bytes as if they were "UTF-8" (which is a lie...).

In short: if you have  a String as in **textRead**, you don't have to convert it at all. If something goes wrong, either the text is already rotten (look at it in the debugger) or gets rotten in the API later on. Check this and come back with more detail? Where is the text that is wrong and where do you exactly read it from or write it to...

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I've updated the question to clarify my problem. The data is getting corrupted when I read them from the database, that's why I was trying to read them as if they where CP1252 and then convert them to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Your database data is in `windows-1252`.  So -- assuming it's being handed back verbatim by the JDBC driver -- when you try to convert it to a Java `String`, *that's* the charset you need to specify:

```
Statement stat = connection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT blah FROM blahblah ...");
byte[] rawbytes = rs.getBytes("whatever");
String textRead = new String(rawbytes, "windows-1252");
```

Is part of the requirement that the data be mailed out as UTF-8?  If so, the UTF-8 part needs to occur on the output side, not the input side.  When you have `String` data in Java, it's stored internally as UTF-16.  So when you serialize it out to the MimeMessage, you again need to pick a charset:

```
mimebodypart.setText(textRead, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense :) I've made so many changes trying to fix it, that I'm starting to write stupid code. Anyway, it's still not working :(. I've tried also with "CP1252" and "ISO-8859-1" (just in case), but the result was the same.

Comment: And no, I'm not required to use UTF-8 for the mails, they can be sent with any encoding. I just need the strings to be actual UTF-8 characters because of the app being run with -Dfile.encoding=utf-8, which corrupts them otherwise.

Comment: OK.  Can you get the actual byte data being returned by `rs.getBinaryStream()` (or `rs.getBytes()`, which might be easier)?  And does it help to set `NLS_LANG` in your program's environment?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

Orace database using WE8MSWIN1252 charset, some VARCHAR2 column data/text containing the euro-sign (€) in it. Sending the text using JavaMail gave problems on the euro-sign.

Finally it works. Two important things you should check/do:

- be sure to use the most recent Oracle JDBC driver for the Java version you use.
- specify the charset (prefer: UTF-8) in JavaMail, e.g.
  MimeMessage.setSubject(String text, "UTF-8")
  MimeMessage.setText(String text, "UTF-8").
  That way the email text gets UTF-8 encoded.
  NOTE: Because RFC 821 restricts mail messages to 7-bit US-ASCII, 8-bit character or binary data needs to be encoded into a 7-bit format. The email header "Content-Transfer-Encoding" specifies the encoding used. For more information: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the conversion in the database?  Instead of:

```
SELECT blah FROM blahblah
```

Try

```
SELECT convert(blah, 'WE8MSWIN1252', 'UTF8') FROM blahblah
```